# Cannot reset visual state of Grid in LongListSelector after SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I implemented `VisualStateManager` to highlight a selected item in `LongListSelector`.

The selected item is highlighted during the `SelectionChanged` event, but the problem is when the event is executed completely, the selected item is still highlighted. Even if I navigate away from the page and get back to the original page, the item is still highlighted. If I add `selector.SelectedItem = null;` at the end of the `SelectionChanged` event, it goes through the method again until it finally throws a `Object reference not set to instance of an object` exception.

How exactly do I reset the visual state of the selected item to `Normal` once it's out of use ?

`SelectionChanged` event:

```
private async void POIS_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<CustomUserControl> userControlList = new List<CustomUserControl>();
        GetItemsRecursive<CustomUserControl>(PoiLongListSelector, ref userControlList);

        //seleted
        if(e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && e.AddedItems[0] != null)
        {
            foreach (CustomUserControl userControl in userControlList)
            {
                if (e.AddedItems[0].Equals(userControl.DataContext))
                {
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(userControl, "Selected", true);
                }
            }
        }
        //Unselected
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 && e.RemovedItems[0] != null)
        {
            foreach (CustomUserControl userControl in userControlList)
            {
                if (e.RemovedItems[0].Equals(userControl.DataContext))
                {
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(userControl, "Normal", true);
                }
            }
        }

        LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;
        PoiData ld = selector.SelectedItem as PoiData;
        string navigateUrl = "";
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        SetProgressIndicator(true);
        //CHECK IF RETURNING NULL
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Getting GPS data";
        GeoCoordinate coordinate = await GetLocation(ctsPoi.Token);
        if (coordinate != null)
        {
            string passedUrl = GenerateUrl(coordinate, ld.Type);
            if (passedUrl != null)
            {
                SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Getting POI data";
                string jsonData = await GetJsonDataFromGoogle(passedUrl, ld.Type);
                if (jsonData != null)
                {
                    string url = SerializeJsonData(jsonData, ld.Type);
                    if (url != null)
                    {
                        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Done";
                        navigateUrl = string.Format("/ViewDirection.xaml?serializedData={0}", url);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(navigateUrl != "")
            (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri(navigateUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

`CustomUserControl` which has the `VisualStateManager` xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,15" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid Name="MainGrid" Opacity="1" Visibility="Visible" >
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush>
                        <Color>#ff00bfff</Color>
                    </SolidColorBrush>
                </Grid.Background>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Grid.Column="0" Width="65" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Height="65" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                               FontSize="30" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <ProgressBar x:Name="ATMBar" Visibility="Visible"
                         Opacity="0"
                                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                             Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                             IsIndeterminate="True"
                                             Style="{StaticResource CustomIndeterminateProgressBar}" />

        </Grid>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid" />

                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ATMBar" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

`LongListSelector` xaml:

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="PoiLongListSelector" Margin="12,-20,0,75"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Poi.Items}"
                                        SelectionChanged="POIS_SelectionChanged">
     <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <myUserControl:CustomUserControl />
                        </DataTemplate>
     </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try something different to highlight the element?, you can binding a background color property or something like that after the selection changed method, if you are using  the mvvm pattern well you should have the INotifypropertyChange, so, it must change this value to some other for do the binding to that property

Comment: I got rid of this implementation and changed the way I wanted to make things work. Thanks for your answer anyway :)